# Add SDNestedTable to a subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Hello there fellow programmers,

I am wondering how to add the SDNestedTable into a project of mine.

Here is the source code for the SDNestedTable:

https://github.com/serverdensity/ios-SDNestedTable

I would like to add this table to a subview of one of my XIB's in my project.

Thanks, hopefully someone can help me out! :)

Comment: @MateusNunes If you download the SDNestedTable, and run it on the iOS simulator, you will see a menu structure. I want to be able to put this view into a subview of one of my XIB files replacing a TableView view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a UITableView to your XIB file, then click on the second tab (right side panel) and in that make the class the SDNestedTable rather than your UITableView so it makes it that class instead, assuming also that SDNestedTable is a subclass of UITableViewController.

You should be able to then add your property to your .h file and attach it in your XIB:

```
@property(nonatomic, weak)IBOutlet SDNestedTable *nestedTable;
```

and in your .m file will go all the delegate methods you need that are also listed at the bottom of the github link you've provided, similarly to a UITableView and the dataSource and delegate methods they have I would imagine.

Comment: I am getting the error "unknown type name 'SDNestedTable'". In the "how to" section of the read me it says "Create a subclass of SDNestedTable." How is this done? or have you already mentioned it in your answer and I am just missing a point?

Comment: and do I just drag all of the files for the Github link into my project, or select ones? I'm sorry for all these questions. I'm learning.

Comment: You should add the entire 'SDNestedTable' folder into your project, as these are the files you'll be using.  I'm not quite sure if you'll actually need to make a subclass of SDNestedTable to use it, as subclassing it will just allow you to further override and customize its features.

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems (based upon the review of your actual source code that you posted in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791411/works-on-ios-simulator-but-not-on-iphone/12792066)):

1. You need to make sure you include the NIBs and PNG files in your "Copy Bundle Resources";
2. If you are going to support iOS 6, there is a bug in `SDNestedTable` and you have to change the `cellIndexPath` of `SDGroupCell` from `assign` to `retain`;
3. If you're adding the `SDNestedTable` (with its own controller) as a subview of `SDNestedTableController` as a subview, then you should use [view controller containment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81).

All of this is explained in greater detail in my other answer to this question:

- [Works on iOS Simulator but not on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791411/works-on-ios-simulator-but-not-on-iphone/12792066#12792066)