# Subclass crash - iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am getting this error when I am trying to make a new file of a certain subclass:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SDNestedTableViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MenuViewController in MenuViewController.o
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SDNestedTableViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MenuViewController in MenuViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I made a file called `MenuViewController` a subclass of `SDNestedTableViewController`

[Here is the link](https://github.com/serverdensity/ios-SDNestedTable) to the subclass files.

Any ideas?

P.S. Overall I am trying to [Add SDNestedTable to a subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788043/add-sdnestedtable-to-a-subview) and if you could help with that, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you made sure in your

Project Settings > Build Phases > Compile Sources

That all your .m files are in there for those files?(MenuViewController && SDNestedTableView Controller)?

Comment: ahh yes, this was the problem. If you would be so kind could you attempt at the question I linked to in this question. (Still haven't solved it) thanks!!