# Works on iOS Simulator but not on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

The line of code works fine on the iOS Simulator 6.0, but is crashing when I try to run it on my iPhone, also running iOS6.

```
[menuView addSubview:mvc.view];
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

This is the more complete version of the code:

```
SDMenuViewController *mvc = [[SDMenuViewController alloc] init];
[menuView addSubview:mvc.view];
```

And this is what it is crashing with:

```
2012-10-08 21:32:32.423 CrunchCalculator1-2[21019:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/EDD23933-CE20-4AFD-A2B1-CDD56AD658E8/CrunchCalculator1-2.app> (loaded)' with name 'SDNestedTableView''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x39cd03e7 0x35ece963 0x39cd0307 0x39ee0fd1 0x39ee05ff 0x39dd9031 0x39e0786d 0x39d63419 0xb20d9 0x39d63541 0x39da3d29 0x39d9fac5 0x39de1199 0xb17c5 0x39da4a71 0x39da45f5 0x39d9c803 0x39d44ce7 0x39d44775 0x39d441b7 0x31e145f7 0x31e14227 0x39ca53e7 0x39ca538b 0x39ca420f 0x39c1723d 0x39c170c9 0x39d9b43d 0x39d98289 0xb1523 0x3792fb20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Thanks!

Comment: What error is it crashing with?

Comment: Is your entire SDMenuViewController defined in the init method?  Or do you have a XIB / Storyboard file with the GUI?

Comment: @Kitsune I updated the question with the error

Comment: @Aaron I have this for the init in the SDMenuViewController: 

- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"SDNestedTableView" bundle:nil])
    {
        // do init stuff
    }
    return self;
}

I woudn't know what to do otherwise

Comment: Have you tried deleting/cleaning and then re-running it on your iPhone? Might be an issue where it's running a version of the bundle that doesn't have it built in....things like that happen to me all the time using Xcode

Comment: @serenn just tried that, no success

Comment: Can you develop a simple, small sample application that demonstrates the same problem and which you can distribute? Solving problems like these are far easier when you can provide the full source.

Comment: @ericgorr the actual project is less than 1mb so here it is: http://www.speedyshare.com/Ez9PA/CrunchCalculator1-2

Comment: Clean the project and delete the app from your phone.

Comment: @Rob right, I uploaded it again. Should work now

Comment: @Rob yes, this shoudl work: http://www.speedyshare.com/atGMR/CrunchCalculator1-2.zip

Comment: Still looking at the code, but you should run the code through the static analyzer (shift-command-B or "Product" - "Analyze") which will point out a few simple things.

Comment: Hmm. This doesn't even work on my simulator (Xcode 4.5). That `SDNestedTableView.nib` has an owner with a class of `EFMNestedTables` but I don't see that in your project?!? I changed that to SDNestedTableViewController. I presume that's right. Also the project didn't include the NIBs or the PNGs in projects "Copy Bundle Resources", and I had to add those, too. At least it's now running in the simulator...

Comment: @SirKaydian I've updated my answer below with a bunch of tactical changes I had to make to project in order to get it to run on both simulator and device.

Comment: @Rob thanks, I'll take a look at everything tommorrow and let you know how it goes. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how it worked on your simulator (when I tried it on mine, I got the crash you list in your original question). Anyway, you can fix it by looking at the following items:

- The main problem is that the NIB was not included in the bundle. Add it to the project target's "Copy Bundle Resources", e.g.:

[image: Copy Bundle Resources]

- While you're looking at your "Copy Bundle Resources", you'll also want to include `SDSubCell.xib`, `SDGroupCell.xib`, and add all of those PNG files, too.
- As an aside, while it doesn't apparently cause the crash, the "File Owner" base class in `SDNestedTableView` NIB refers to a class that doesn't exist anywhere in this project. That can't be good. Anyway, you probably want to change that to `SDMenuViewController` or `SDNestedTableViewController`;

[image: Set File's Owner Base Class]

---

It's a little unrelated to your crash, but as I look at the project, I see a worrying construct:

```
SDMenuViewController *mvc = [[SDMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SDNestedTableView" bundle:nil];
[menuView addSubview:mvc.view];
```

You're creating a controller, grabbing its view, and either letting the view controller fall out of scope and be released (if you were using ARC) or leaking it (if not ARC).

I wasn't entirely sure from the original question whether you were doing `addSubview` as a way of transitioning to a new view (which is really bad practice) or whether you were doing view controller containment. As I look at the code, it appears you're doing the latter, though you're missing a few calls in your code. You might want to read up on [view controller containment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81). And also check out that [WWDC 2011 session 102](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102).

Anyway, those two lines of code above with the view controller `alloc`/`init` and the subsequent `addSubview` will leak in your non-ARC project (and would crash it if you ever went to ARC) and your view hierarchy is out of sync with your view controller hierarchy. I'd suggest you might want:

```
SDMenuViewController *mvc = [[[SDMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SDNestedTableView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[self addChildViewController:mvc];
[mvc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[menuView addSubview:mvc.view];
```

Note the `autorelease` on that first line.

View controller containment can be powerful, but you want to make sure you do some of this basic housekeeping.

---

One final update:

I notice that there are some bugs that are in this code. First, your use of `currentSection` in `item:setSubItem:forRowAtIndexPath` won't work. You're setting that based upon the last `expandingItem`. So, if you click on one of the main items before expanding either one, the program will crash. Probably best is to eliminate the `currentSection` variable altogether and in `item:setSubItem:forRowAtIndexPath`, use `item.cellIndexPath.row` rather than your variable `currentSection`.

Unfortunately, this fix leads to a more serious problem, there appears to be an iOS 6 bug in the `SDNestedTable` class, itself. If you run this on iOS 6 and you expand your all of your items, scroll to the bottom and then scroll back to the top, the program will crash because the `cellIndexPath` property of the `SDGroupItem *item` returned by `item:setSubItem:forRowAtIndexPath` can be deallocated! If you turn on zombies in iOS 6, you'll see `cellIndexPath` has been released. I went and downloaded the [original version](https://github.com/serverdensity/ios-SDNestedTable) and see the same problem there. The problem appears to be that `cellIndexPath` in `SDGroupCell` is defined as an `assign` property (which means that if iOS determines it no longer needed the `indexPath` it created for its own purposes, it will be released even though `SDGroupCell` maintains an `assign` reference to this released object). Just change the `cellIndexPath` property of `SDGroupCell` from `assign` to `retain`, and this iOS 6 bug goes away. I've informed the developer of `SDNestedTable` of this issue, but this change to `retain` will fix the problem of the code crashing in iOS 6.

*[Edit: The author of `SDNestedTable` agreed with my assessment of the issue, and he reports that this issue has been fixed the latest version. - Rob]*

Best wishes.

Comment: I am trying to display a custom TableView so that it can act somewhat like the notification center in iOS. The way that I have done this was the only way I could get it to work, in answer to my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788043/add-sdnestedtable-to-a-subview but maybe there is a better way to answer the linked question.

Comment: @SirKaydian I've updated my answer given a little more examination of your code, as well as an iOS 6 bug fix for the `SDNestedTable`, itself.

Comment: wow, thank you times a million! This is by far the best. most in depth answer I have ever gotten. Not only did you solve the problem I was having and more, you also taught me things like the view controller containment! Kudos to you my friend!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `initWithNibName:` insead of just `init` in the first line. Not sure regarding your specific issue, but certainly something to try.

Comment: same problem, works on iOS Sim, but not on iPhone. Tried clean and delete as well. Thanks for the effort though

Comment: @Greg Actually, `init` alone is surprisingly good about finding the right NIB. Plus, the `init` method of his base class specifies the NIB name, so he's good either way.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to instantiate a nib called SDNestedTableView.nib and it isn't present. Is the nib included as a project member?

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't included in the bundle. Worse, the base class it referenced didn't exist in his project at all.